# Trying to simplify the expression

Tags: contest-math

Can anybody simplify it? Show me the way of simplification.

The expression is as follows:

$$F(x) = 1 *(1!+x)+2*(2!+x)+ ..+x*(x!+x)$$

for a positive integer $x$ I've tried but nothing got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r$th term $=r(r!+x)=r\cdot r!+rx=(r+1-1)r!+rx=\underbrace{(r+1)!-r!}+rx$

The terms underbraced is Telescoping  and $\sum_{r=1}^xrx=x\sum_{r=1}^xr=x\dfrac{x(x+1)}2$

Comment: awesome answer (+1)

Comment: Thankyou boss for quick response and in so much easy way

Comment: @Frustrated, See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, Can you tell me , value of F(4) for better understanding of "Telescoping" in this answer.

Comment: @Frustrated, If you have understood my  method, you should be able to find $F(x)=?$ then set $x=4$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, F(4)=40, is it? or F(4)=159